# Using C# LINQ Expressions for both Value Types and Reference Types

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, c#-4.0

I'm using MVC for REST so that I can take advantage of Razor for outputting different types.  CSV is one of those outputs.  Instead of writing this template for each input type:

```
ID,Created,Content
@foreach (var item in Model.TimeData)
{
<text>@item.ID,@item.Created,"@Html.Raw(item.Content.Replace("\"", "\"\""))"</text>
}
```

I wanted to make use of `params` and `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to write something like this:

```
@{
    Html.WriteCsv<TimeObject>(Model.TimeData, p => p.ID, p => p.Created, p => p.Content);   
}
```

I started writing a generic `HtmlHelper` and quickly realized I had problems with value types (memberExpression will be  null).  The code below attempts to just write out the CSV heading (ID,Created,Content), but it only outputs "Content" (because ID and Created are value types (`int` and `DateTime`).

```
public static void WriteCsv<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, List<TModel> list, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] expressions)
{
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(propertyInfo.Name + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried replacing `object` with `dynamic`, thinking that would work, but when I quick watch `expression.Body`, it still seems to think it's dealing with an object (the `DebugView` property is `(System.Object)$p.ID`).

Is this impossible in C# 4.0?

Here's the type I'm using it on:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true, Namespace = "urn:test:TimeObject")]
public class TimeObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but using a custom ActionResult would be better.  You can even use the one here: http://notesfor.net/post/2010/06/28/AspNet-custom-ActionResult-CSV.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the value types are properties? maybe they're fields which would require you to cast it as `(FieldInfo)`

Comment: @Talljoe that's an option, but I'd prefer not to use magic strings, which that solution relies on (for ignored fields).  It seems it also does not support complex objects (if CSVUserModel had a User on it, which contained Username and Password).

Comment: @Slaks @Jose It does not work... memberExpression is null.  Here's my TimeObject class: 
[DataContract(IsReference = true, Namespace = "urn:test:TimeObject")]
public class TimeObject
{
[DataMember]
public long ID { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string Content { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

Comment: @Langdon, writing your own is pretty simple or you could build the content in the controller and pass it to FileResult (which does the right thing regarding mime type, optional filename, etc).  I'm not convinced Razor handles non-HTML well.

Comment: +1 for @Talljoe.  Razor is not the right tool for this job.  I think you want to transform your model at the controller level and then spit it out via a simple custom ActionResult.  So at the controller, turn any complex objects or missing fields into the proper string representation or defaults and only then invoke your view / actionresult.

Comment: @Milimetric You're right about using an ActionResult, but the whole reason I was using `params Expression` was to avoid the extra work each time I go to use this.  I'll probably take my WriteCsv method, now that it works, and apply it to the `CSVResult` constructor and get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case that the expression references a value type, the compiler has to box the reference; it does so implicitly. This complication means that the expression tree for a Value Type member expression is not simply a MemberExpression, so your cast is returning null.

The following is a general solution for obtaining the property name from a Value Type or Reference Type member expression, taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875720/why-could-an-expressions-body-in-c-net-not-use-properties-of-type-int-double-o):

```
private string GetPropertyName(Expression<Func<object, object>> f) {
    var body = f.Body;
    if (body.NodeType==ExpressionType.Convert)
      body = ((UnaryExpression) body).Operand;
    if ((body as MemberExpression) != null) {
        return (body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }
    return "";
}
```