# C# expression gets converted into different expression by itself

Tags: c#, expression

I have a following model class:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<PostRating> Ratings { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<PostAction> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

I need to expose some properties using expressions, and everything seems to be ok with all properties besides with CreatedAt. When I need to expose that one, the expression somehow gets converted into a somewhat different expression.

I think it's best if just show picture of my code, and the values that the debugger sees.

[image]

As you can see, something strange had happened to that CreatedAt property expresssion.
But if I change type of that expression to `Expression<Func<Post, DateTime>>`, it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5707561/9678775 (DateTime is a value type (struct). It is wrapped into the Convert() to do the boxing)

Comment: Note that DateTime is a `struct` (a value type). To handle it like an object (i.e., reference type), it needs to be boxed (i.e., converted/boxed into a reference type). That is basically what the expression in the debugger tooltip hints at. See here about boxing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Answer (score 2):

You're likely running into boxing issues. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) has more on that, but basically boxing is the process of converting a value type (like your `DateTime`) to an `object`. It is an implicit conversion and would explain why you are seeing that behavior. If that is undesirable, you'd be better of using the type in your expression.

Comment: `Post.AuthorId` is a `string` which is a reference type.